# Trying to convert GeoPandas Dataframe with date to ESRI Shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, fiona, pandas

Created a GeoPandas dataframe from an excel sheet. The schema for the dataframe is:

```py
{'geometry': 'Point',
 'properties': OrderedDict([
        ...
              ('DISTID', 'int'),
              ('PROVID', 'int'),
              ('date', 'datetime')])}
```

Edit: Thought I should clarify - the date field is saved as type datetime, but it only has date.

But when I run `gdf.to_file('sample.shp', driver = "ESRI Shapefile")` I get the error `DriverSupportError: ESRI Shapefile does not support datetime fields`.

I tried converting the datetime field to date by using `gdf['date'] = pd.to_datetime(gdf['date']).dt.date` but then that throws a `ValueError: Invalid field type <class 'datetime.date'>`. Kind of stumped on what to do, I'd like to keep the dates in the Shapefile. I'm using GeoPandas version 0.11.0 and Fionas 1.8.21.

Edit 2: Should have been more specific with what I tried. I attempted to change the field type using the solutions here [Changing shapefile's field type using fiona?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281895/changing-shapefiles-field-type-using-fiona) to no avail. If I try to change the schema, I get `ValueError: Record does not match collection schema:`.

I then tried to use the `gdf['date'] = pd.to_datetime(gdf['date']).date()` but the fucntion didn't even run, giving me `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'date'`. Then I did `gdf['date'] = pd.to_datetime(gdf['date']).dt.date`, and while the function worked, I got  `ValueError: Invalid field type <class 'datetime.date'>` when trying to export as a shapefile.

Edit 3:

the entire excel file, when exported as a pandas dateframe, has only one field 'date' with type `datetime64[ns]`. The dates are all in the form [image]. They do not have any time attached.

I do the following:

```py
pdf = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx", index_col=0)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pdf, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(pdf.Longitude, pdf.Latitude))
```

First, I tried:

```py
gdf['date'] = pd.to_datetime(gdf['date']).dt.date
```

Tried to export to shapefile using `gdf.to_file('sample.shp', driver = "ESRI Shapefile")`, gave me `ValueError: Invalid field type <class 'datetime.date'>`

Tried to simply convert it to a string, and then export, as suggested in the answer.

```
gdf['date'] = gdf['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

but this didn't work either. When I did `gdf.info()` it would show that the type was no longer `datetime`, but `object` instead. And yet it throws `ValueError: Invalid field type <class 'datetime.time'>`

Comment: see this answer - https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/267419/79

Comment: @IanTurton that's for both date and time, my date only has date

Comment: it's a `datetime` no matter what you store in it - so don't do that

Comment: @IanTurton How do I change the type? Tried the methods listed here (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281895/changing-shapefiles-field-type-using-fiona) but none of them work, and give me a value error instead

Comment: you need to edit your question to show what you've tried and what went wrong

Comment: @IanTurton my bad, edited it to be more detailed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the datetimes to strings/objects.

I have a datetime field called `date`:

```
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file('/home/bera/GIS/Data/lämningar_sverige.gpkg', layer='lämningar_sverige_point')
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') #Convert the datetimes to strings
df.to_file('/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/datetimes.shp')
```

Comment: thank you! i'll do this for now, at least until i find a way to keep it only as a date

Comment: Not possible as far as I know. Dates as stored as `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`, with a specification of AM or PM.

Comment: oh okay. unfortunately when i do this i get `ValueError: Invalid field type <class 'datetime.time'>`. Does it work completely fine for you?

Comment: Then you havent converted the datetime to string. Add a sample of your excel file as text to your question and the code you are using to create the geodataframe, and the code you are using to create the datetimes and convert to text and export to shapefile

Comment: edited the original question, not much more relevant in the code now besides what I've written